# $(this).ajaxSubmit is not a function

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using rails 3.1.3, and jquery.form.js version 2.9.4, and jquery 1.7.1.
I put some console print statements in jquery.form.js, so I can see (in the firebug console) that it has loaded.

And I set up my form like this:

```
var options = {
  success: s.update_or_add_contact_response, type: 'post', 
  dataType: 'json',  url:  s.update_contact_path
};

$('form#new_user').submit(function() {
  $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
  return false;
});
```

And when I click on a button to submit the form I get the following error message in the firebug console:

$(this).ajaxSubmit is not a function

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

This is new function so you have to add other lib file after jQuery lib

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

it will work.. 
I have tested.. 
hope it will work for you..

Answer (score 2):

I have never used this function, but your syntax looks correct according to the doc at: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit.

Without seeing all of your code I would guess either you aren't linking the jQuery plugin, or you aren't wrapping your code in `$( document ).ready( function(  ) { //code } );` as such.

Look at your source code and make sure that the plugin is being linked. Is it there?

Put in an alert just above `var options`. Does it output?

Comment: +1 Sounds like either the plugin is not linked correctly, or the code is executing before it's loaded.

Comment: OP: "I put some console print statements in jquery.form.js, so I can see (in the firebug console) that it has loaded." So the issue wouldn't seem to be inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing the document.ready wrapper?

```
$(function() { // same as document.ready
    var options = {
      success: s.update_or_add_contact_response, type: 'post', 
      dataType: 'json',  url:  s.update_contact_path
    };

    $('form#new_user').submit(function() {
      $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery must be conflicting with other js files, you can find some help from [here](http://codeimpossible.com/2010/01/13/solving-document-ready-is-not-a-function-and-other-problems/), replacing `$` by `jQuery` in the code might help.